# zero vector in linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:R^n  \implies R^m $ be a linear transformation. In this case, I have two questions.

1. Is it always true that $T(0)=0$ where the zero vectors live in the apropriate spaces?
   My answer: True. Because zero vector lies in every dimension.
2. Does $S(0)=0$ mean that S is linear ? Is there any counter example ?

My answer: I think S is linear.

Please help me to clarify my solution process.

Comment: For 1), since $T$ is linear, $T(0)=T(0+0)=T(0)+T(0)$, so subtracting $T(0)$ from both sides gives $T(0)=0$

Comment: nice explanation. got your point.

Comment: $S(0)=0$ doesn't imply $S$ is linear. Take $S: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ as $S(x_1,x_2)=(x_1^2, x_2^2,0)$

Comment: $S(x_1,x_2) = S(x_1^2,x_2^2,0)$ So $ S(0) = S(0,0)=(0,0,0) $ SO S is linear

Comment: How do you define linear transformation?

Comment: A [Linear Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) has a very specific meaning in mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two distinctly different questions here.

For any linear transformation, T, is T(0)= 0?

Yes!   A linear transformation, T, has the property that T(u+ v)= T(u)+ T(v).  In particular, if v= 0 then T(u+ 0)= T(u)+ T(0).  But u+ 0= u so that says T(u)= T(u)+ T(0).  Subtract T(u) from both sides of that equation to get 0= T(0).

If S is a transformation such that S(0)= 0 is S a linear transformation?

No!  Not necessarily.  Given a non-zero vector v and define S(u)= v for u non-zero and  S(0)= 0.  That is a transformation such that S(0)= 0 but is not a linear transformation.

Comment: Without more definition, $S$ might, or might not, be a linear transformation.

Comment: For example, f(x): R-> R, defined by f(x)= x^2, satisfies f(0)= 0 but is not linear.